# Placeholder replacement not working with flyway test extensions

Tags: flyway

I'm trying to use placeholders with flyway test extension 1.7.0.
  I defined a placeholder in flyway.properties:

```
  flyway.placeholders.schema_name=MYSCHEMA
```

My sql script looks like that:

```
  create schema ${schema_name};
```

When running the flyway test, I'm getting the following error:

```
117157 [main] DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.sql.SqlScript  - Found statement at line 1: create schema ${schema_name};
117157 [main] DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.sql.SqlStatement  - Executing SQL: create schema ${schema_name}
117157 [main] ERROR com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator  - com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 1: create schema ${schema_name}
117158 [main] ERROR com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator  - Caused by org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Unknown JDBC escape sequence: {: {schema_name}
117158 [main] DEBUG com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator  - Finished migrating to version 1.1 (execution time 00:00.005s)
```

So it looks like the placeholder replacement is not working.
By the way, my flyway.properties file is loaded successfully (I'm using it for other values like jdbc url, too).

Does someone know what could be the problem here?

**EDIT1** It looks like the configure method in the Flyway class is not called. Do I have to add something to the application context?

**EDIT2** One solution we found is to set the placeholders in the applicationcontext:

```
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway"
    depends-on="dataSourceRef">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceRef" />
    <property name="placeholders" >
      <map>
        <entry key="schema_name" value="${flyway.placeholders.schema_name}" />
     </map> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

But we are still looking for a better solution ...

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late answer. I saw your question today for first time.

I accepted your issue see also http://code.google.com/p/flyway-test-extensions/issues/detail?id=14.

The default implementation and example show not how it can work or give enough utilities to solve it.

The solution can only be done with spring part depends on the implementation of flyway-test-extensions.

**a.) First part of a solution**

Its not a complete solution, because replacement of *flyway.placeholders.* will be done inside Flyway by method *configure* and that we can not invoke.

Put following in your application context:

```
<!-- also need this as additional include part  -->

xmlns:util="http : //www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http: // www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http: // www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
```

and

```
<!-- flyway part -->
<util:properties id="flyway.prop" location="/flyway.properties"/>

<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" depends-on="dataSourceRef">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceRef"/>
    <property name="placeholders" ref="flyway.prop"/>
</bean>
```

But than in your flyway.properties file you must remove *flyway.placeholders.* from the property definition. I think that not complete wanted solution.

**b.) Second part**

**EDIT**

Better solution use checkin from the current flyway-test-extension development.(http://code.google.com/p/flyway-test-extensions/source/detail?r=921f44bb206527db88f4b59faaf7ea968a743233)

- FlywayHelperFactory.java as a factory implementation for Flyway. Put this as part of your test sources.
  This should also work for a 1.7 version.
- flywayPropertiesContext.xml as a new application context. Put this as a test/resources in a directory called context.
  This contains two sample solution how the flyway.properties can be loaded. 
  Note: 
  This context do not use the jdbc.properties variable it use the flyway properties instead!
  This context should also work together with flyway-test-extension 1.7.0
- change your test settings and use `@ContextConfiguration(locationsForMirgation = {
  "/context/flywayPropertiesContext.xml"  })` as a new configuration.

florian